# Disable formatting on textarea

Tags: wp-autop, esc-textarea

I'm using the following code in my plugin to display a `<textarea>` field on a page:

```
echo '<textarea required="required" name="Message" class="textarea" cols="70" rows="10">'.esc_textarea($message).'</textarea>';
```

However, WordPress seems to be inserting `<p>` and `<br />` tags into the textarea contents if the message contains newline characters. I'm assuming this is being caused by the default wpautop() filter.

Is there a way to disable filtering of `<textarea>` contents on a page?

**Edit**

Some more information about how my plugin works. It creates a hook for `the_content`, which will append data to the contents of certain pages. I still want `wpautop` formatting to be applied to the appended content, just not for the `<textarea>` field.

Here is a rough outline of how my plugin is setup:

```
function get_special_content()
{
    $text = '';

    // Customized content is appended to text here
    // including the textarea field

    return $text;
}

function my_plugin_content_hook($content)
{
    if(is_some_special_page()) {
        return $content.get_special_content();
    }

    return $content;
}

add_action('the_content', 'my_plugin_content_hook');
```

Comment: Please post more code. How does this plugin work? Is it hooked to `the_content` maybe?

Comment: Yes, I'm hooking `the_content`. I've edited the question to provide more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a priority to push your function to the end of the hook queue.

```
add_action('the_content', 'my_plugin_content_hook', 1000);
```

Then, in your `get_special_content` function you will need to apply `wpautop` manually to the content to which you want it applied.

```
function get_special_content()
{
    $text = '';
    $autopeed = 'content to autop';
    $text .= apply_filters('wpautop',$autopeed);
    $text .= "your textarea code";
    return $text;
}
```

I believe that will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. However, I found a simpler solution and posted it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that `wpautop` will preserve the contents of `<pre>` tags. By placing a `<pre>` tag around the `<textarea>` tag, I am able to prevent the text area contents from being modified.

```
echo '<pre><textarea>'.esc_textarea($message).'</textarea></pre>';
```

I'm not sure why `wpautop` doesn't also ignore `<textarea>` tags by default. I can't imagine a scenario where you would want `wpautop` to be applied to the contents of a text area. Maybe it's just an oversight.